# "Advise" vs. "advise that"

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

> ... and I want to **advise** they, too, come for a session.
>
> ... and I want to **advise that** they, too, come for a session.

The first is how I first wrote it. Do I need *that*?

Comment: It's a "busy" sentence anyway (without even knowing what comes before your first comma), so I would keep "that" to make it easier for the reader to parse.

Comment: It seemed a bit more fluid without out it, but, yes, it makes it easier to parse. The 'comes before' part is busy too. In essence, 'Your sessions are great. I have found another person, and I want to advise they, too, come.'

Comment: "Fluid" is not the same thing as "clear". Native speakers always want to talk faster, so they leave things out whenever they can. Non-native speakers don't know when they can get away with it, so "fluidity" is not something they should aim for. _Fluency_ includes being able to speak and understand at normal speech rates in informal contexts; it's not just fluidity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two patterns for "advise":

> advise [somebody] that (sentence)

eg

- He advised them that they should object
- He advised that somebody should follow them

and

> advise somebody to (non-finite clause)

eg

> He advised them to object

Your second example is my first pattern, but I do not find your first pattern to be grammatical.

Comment: I don't really think it's really a matter of "grammaticality". In Shakespeare's *King Lear, Act 4, Scene 5* we have [Therefore I do advise you, take this note](http://books.google.com/books?id=RcA8AAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA84&dq=%22advise+you+take%22&hl=en&ei=u1egTpCFBNT-8QPf8OXwBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAjgU#v=onepage&q=%22advise%20you%20take%22&f=false), where I don't think the comma makes any difference (nor did Samuel Johnson in the link).

Comment: I think the comma does make a difference, but I see what you mean about Johnson. It appears that it was grammatical in Johnson's day, but I do not find it so now.

Comment: Perhaps we have different ideas on what "grammatical" means. All permutations (*that* before *you*, or *to/comma/nothing* after it) seem grammatical to me. Some might be dated or otherwise unusual, but really that's all just style.

Answer (score 2):

Both work, though they sound rather clunky. Both require some processing, but the second one is easier to read, IMO. I would write something like:

- and my advice is...
- and I [want to/would] advise them to also come for a session.
- and I would recommend they also come for a session.

Comment: 'I advise that they' seems a more frequent usage than 'I advise they' according to a raw Google search.